# mvc.net 4 view not showing ViewBag.Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I created empty mvc.net 4 application in visual studio 2012. 
I added a "Service" controller:

```
public class ServiceController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Service/s

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.text = "EEEE";
            return View();
        }

    }
```

and I right clicked on ActionResult, and added a view called "Index", and I put in this code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<br>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
```

And when I go to link "http://localhost:4376/Service/Index" , all the output I get is: "

### Index

, and there is no "EEEE" text shown. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ViewBag.text` is not `ViewBag.Message`. Change the view code to

```
<h2>@ViewBag.text</h2>
```

or the controller code to

```
ViewBag.Message = "EEEE";
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't see that. :)